# django, normal post form is not sending file data to server,

Tags: python, django, file-upload, submit

I'm wondering why this is happening:

I'm sending file data with form in POST, but all the time it says:

```
Key 'file' not found in <QueryDict:
{
 u'datum': [u'aaa'],
 u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'USAbRrgU92yj7KFpZHuxf9bWufgnwC4N'], 
 u'anzeige': [u' aaaa'], 
 u'titel': [u' aaa']
}
```

This is my html:

```
<form id="myform" action="/anzeige_save/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
{% csrf_token %} 
<textarea style="width: 450px" id="titel"  name="titel"> </textarea>
<textarea name="anzeige" id="anzeige" 
    style="height: 180px; width: 450px"> </textarea>  
<input type="text" id="datum" name="datum" >
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="40" maxlength="100000">
<input type="button" value="speichern" 
    onclick="javascript:submitform()" />
</form>

<script>
  function submitform(){
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
  }
</script>
```

and part my view is this:

```
anzeige=Anzeige(titel=request.POST['titel'], 
                anzeige=end_anzeige, 
                date=datetime.datetime.now(), 
                datum=request.POST['datum'],
                file=request.FILES['file'])
anzeige.save()
```

I'm actually submitting correctly, the form should also submit the file in QueryDict like other queries. Can someone help me to figure out what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: can you please provide the code for the Anzeige class and its save method?

Comment: i think, it is not about saving, the problem is coming on the way to save, before saving..

Comment: why did you remove the error from the post? unless you type it again, the question isn't completely clear. anyway, a better approach would be creating a model class and a form that handles the uploading. if you already have them, please provide the code.

Comment: i didnot remove the error, someone is editing all the time my question..

Comment: it's back. anyway, i suggest another thing: you don't want to handle a file upload with plain javascript, you'll better want to use ajax to send your post request to django, or django directly. try to remove the javascript submit function and modify your button as a simple html submit button, then tell me if it works for you or not

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo this is what i did 20 minutes ago, but one guy suggested that file upload thru ajax is not possible, is it true?

Comment: if it's not possible via ajax, i don't see how it can be with plain javascript :)

Comment: i also dont see what it cannot be possible, there is no difference between normal and ajax submit except some other irrelevant issues

Comment: that's not exactly my point, but still we're on the same: your friend was wrong hehe :)

Comment: yeahh, i was really wondering, but anyway, i found the answer to the problem, i has typo: ``request.POST['file']`` while checking for POST in my view. now, i am getting access denied to ``upload_to`` place, you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Use a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)** instead of a form, unless you have a good reason not to.
2. **Your HTML will display a blank form** if the form doesn't validate, without mentioning the errors nor previously entered values, see [customizing a form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#customizing-the-form-template) for correct usage.
3. **It is normal that request.POST['file'] does not exist**, it's in request.FILES['file'], but it must be saved before it can be used in a model. If you use a ModelForm, it is automatic. Else, see [handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/?from=olddocs#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model).

Comment: great @jpic, my typo was in ``request.POST['file']`` i just oversaw. now it is saying: 
``SuspiciousOperation at /anzeige_save/
Attempted access to '\anzeige\D-d-M-Y\burning.txt' denied.``

Comment: Probably your upload_to callback returns an absolute path. It should return a relative path. It will automatically be placed in MEDIA_ROOT.